# Angularjs routing not working with base href

Tags: javascript, angularjs

as a sample program, I downloaded [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3ozt9s?p=preview) from a tutorial to test tab routing in different pages. I downloaded the complete zip and ran as it is (*e.g. files in same directory, and links are CDN*) but it didn't work. I think the angular file is not included as it was showing this output:

Click one of the following choices.

```
tab 1<br/>
tab 2

{{ path }}   //supposed to model the variable
```

But it works fine in the plunker. Is the problem with base href path or version? I tried including my own files for angular.min.js instead of the link but it still doesn't work.

Here's the html:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-semver="1.2.7" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    <p>Click one of the following choices.</p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/tab1')}"><a href="#/tab1">tab 1</a>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/tab2')}"><a href="#/tab2">tab 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <pre>{{ path }}</pre>
  </div>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />'); wrong

Comment: Could you tell whats wrong? It works fine in the plunker I linked.

Comment: I think I agree with @DavidLin in that you are using the <base> tag incorrectly. It seems like you are attempting to use it to determine the location of files referenced on the page (that is <script> and <link> tags), but it only determines the base of links that might be visited (that is <a> tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `document.location` is returning to you an `Object`, try `document.location.origin`.

Comment: Still not working. Why does the document.location works in the plunker as you can see?

Comment: When writing links inside of our Angular app in html5mode, we’ll never want to use relative links.
If you are serving your app using the root, it won’t be a problem; however, if you are serving in any
other base route, our Angular app won’t be able to handle it.
Alternatively, you can set the base URL of your app using the <base> tag in the HEAD section of
the HTML document:
<base href="/base/url" />
so if you want make it dynamical you should get base url through document.location.origin

Answer (score 0):

try with `ng-href="tab1"` instead of `href="#/tab1"`